# for model in model_or_iterable: TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I encountered a problem to migrate this model and this admin

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

This error occurs

```
for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable
```

## this is my admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


from .models import User, Province


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fields = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        'Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email')},
        'Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')},
        'Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')},
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'phone_number', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('username', 'phone_number', 'email', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('username_exact',)
    ordering = ('-id',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, my_have_duplicates = super().get_search_results(
            request, queryset, search_term
        )
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(phone_number=search_term_as_int)
        return queryset, my_have_duplicates

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Province)
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(MyUserAdmin)
```

But the program has encountered an error

```
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Likely the error is not here, since there is no `MediaDefiningClass`, unless you "obfuscated" something.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

instead of

```
admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(MyUserAdmin)
```

MyUserAdmin is not a Model but a 'MediaDefiningClass', so it must be a second argument in admin.site.register()